# Jenkins poll or push trigger job run for shared library changes too

Tags: git, jenkins, push-notification, jenkins-pipeline, polling

I have Jenkins `Pipeline` job define in my git repo as.

```
// File: deployment/jenkinsfiles/staging/Merge

@Library("my_shared_lib") _

import com.company.myteam.Constants

pipeline {
    agent { label "common" }

    triggers {
        pollSCM("H/2 * * * *")
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: "50", artifactNumToKeepStr: "50"))
    }

    stages {
        stage ("Staging Merge") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def config = new Constants().repoconfig
                    ansiColor("xterm") {
                        myteam.pipelines.stagingMerge(config)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created jenkins job configuration as below.

[image: Jenkins Job Config]

Now, When I check the `Git Polling Log` its polling `shared-library` too.

```
Started on Feb 25, 2020 5:33:07 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 681f996e689bdeb9cfca2b167002b8ccd99590cb (origin/staging)
using credential github_username_with_token
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github Service Account Username with token
 > git ls-remote -h https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/myrepo # timeout=10
Found 6 remote heads on https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/myrepo
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/staging is: 681f996e689bdeb9cfca2b167002b8ccd99590cb - already built by 53
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision e80628ec7c9dbc59decbc81a3b884dcaa963a8dc (refs/remotes/origin/master)
using credential github_username_with_token
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories
 > git config remote.origin.url https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/jenkins-shared-libraries.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/jenkins-shared-libraries.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github Service Account Username with token
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/jenkins-shared-libraries.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Polling for changes in
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git log --full-history --no-abbrev --format=raw -M -m --raw e80628ec7c9dbc59decbc81a3b884dcaa963a8dc..869b3a16e07d21a88d557f1857376bfed7717a6e # timeout=10
```

Whenever I change code in `jenkins-shared-library`, its start build for the job.

I tried `workaround` given in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-39615?focusedCommentId=280729&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-280729, but no luck.

I changed my `pollSCM` to `githubPush`, but this also trigger when I change in `shared-library`.

I tried solution given in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41497 as `Ignore on push notifications` for `githubPush()` but still its triggering job.

Before moving to `pipeline`, I had `freestyle` project. Where there is section **Source Code Management**, where we can define the branch, and `githubPush()` was listening on that branch only.

[image: Source Code Management]

When we select project type as `pipeline` there is no **Source code management** section. May be due to that, its listening for all push events.

By `push` or `poll`, I want to restrict my jenkins job to trigger only when there is changes on `myrepo.git` only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix it in this `Task Type`. However, if you could switch to the multi-branch pipeline. This issue is addressed by that Task type. [image]

Comment: How to check in this ? can you give detail configuration for this ?

Comment: Follow this link https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery/ refer to "Create a Jenkins job for your project" section. It is just 3 steps.

Comment: I tried with `Multibranch`, the issue is, for every push, it trigger for all branches. I need to restrict to single branch.

Comment: Nope. If configured properly. Only the branch with latest commit will be triggered automatically. How are you triggering the pipeline? With a git webhook isn't it?

Comment: GIT Push, for now

Comment: @Nilesh Iam also facing the same issue did you got a solution for this issue

Comment: @nilesh1212 I created job which will be trigger by git push, and that job tigger another pipeline. I can't find for multibranch.